# How do let CSS change the inset shadow on li hover, instead of resetting it?

Tags: css, menu, shadow, nav, css-selectors

I have got a small problem with my list item on hover.

The menu bar has a small inset shadow at the bottom, defined on the li items. On li:hover the small inset at the bottom changes to a inset shadow on all 4 sides.

I`m pretty happy about how the menu reacts, except for the li:lastchild. On hover it first delete the bottom & right inset shadow and then prints the new 4 sided inset shadow. Al the other li items just change the shadow from a single bottom to all 4 sides, without resetting the shadow.

I know the css shadow part is not written very clean. But because the hover has to CHANGE te shadow instead of replace i cant simple commit a statement on multiple selectors. (If you guys know a way to do this please feel free to comment!)

So my question is, how do i get a different inset shadow on the li:lastchild which will change on hover instead of getting replaced?

The code on [cedepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BFznK)

```
        <ul class="hoofd-menu menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item I</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item II</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item III</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item IV</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item V</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu Item VI</a></li>
    </ul>


    <style> 
        .menu li {
            margin: 0 0 0 -4px;
            padding: 15px 15px;

        }

        /* Menu Item Hover effect */

        .menu li {
            box-shadow:     0 -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,     /* dark shadow      */
                            2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      /* white - top      */
                            2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);       /* white - bottom   */
        }

        li:last-child.menu-item {
            box-shadow:     -9px 0px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,   /*dark shadow right */
                            0px -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,   /*dark shadow       */
                            2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      /* white - top      */
                            2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);       /* white - bottom   */
        }

        li:first-child.menu-item {
            box-shadow:      0px -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,  /* dark shadow      */
                            -2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),     /* white - left     */
                             2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),     /* white - top      */
                             2px 2px 3px  0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);     /* white - bottom   */
        }

        .menu li:hover {
            cursor:         pointer;
            box-shadow:     -1px -1px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset, /* dark shadow      */
                            2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      /* white - top      */
                            2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);       /* white - bottom   */
        }

        .menu li:hover>a {
            text-shadow:    -1px -1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);             /* text shadow      */
        }

        li:hover:last-child.menu-item {
            box-shadow:     -1px -1px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset, /* dark shadow      */
                            2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      /* white - top      */
                            2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);       /* white - bottom   */
        }

        li:hover:first-child.menu-item {
            box-shadow:      -1px -1px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,  /* dark shadow    */
                             -2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),     /* white - top     */
                             2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      /* white - top     */
                             2px 2px 3px  0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);      /* white - bottom  */
        }


        /******************************************************************************************/
        /* Round corners                                                                          */
        /******************************************************************************************/
        li:first-child.menu-item {
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:  5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius:      5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft:     5px;
            border-top-left-radius:         5px;
        }

        li:last-child.menu-item {
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:     5px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright:    5px;
            border-top-right-radius:        5px;
        }

        /******************************************************************************************/
        /* Color palette                                                                          */
        /******************************************************************************************/

        a                       {color: #0861a5;}
        a:hover                 {color: #d98500;}
        .menu li:hover>a,
        .menu a                 {color: #dddddd;}

        body                    {background-color: #b8d3e2;}
        .menu li                {background-color: #87a0af;}

        .menu                   {font-family:       Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
        a                       {text-decoration:   none;}

a, .menu li>a {
    transition:         1.5s ease 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:    1.5s ease 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease 0.2s;
    -o-transition:      1.5s ease 0.2s;
}

a:hover, .menu li, .menu li:hover>a {
    transition:         0.4s ease 0.6s;
    -moz-transition:    0.4s ease 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease 0.6s;
    -o-transition:      0.4s ease 0.6s;
}

ul, li, ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

ul {
  margin: 100px 50px;
}

/* algemeen menu*/
.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Please post your code here as well as linking to an external site. If that external site goes down no one will be able to see your code.

Comment: thnx @BillyMoat, added the code.

Comment: What are the li:first-child.menu-item and li:last-child.menu-item classes for?? Shouldn't the shadows be the same for all buttons? ALso, if you delete them, your problem goes away!

Comment: Yes, the css would be a lot smaller if i just delete them, but the li:first-child and li:last-child create the rounded corners. The li:last-child has a small shadow to the right to simulate the light source. I know it`s a small detail, but it looks better with the shadows.

Comment: did you try replacing the  li:last-child.menu-item class with ul:after

Comment: I have seen your code working fine in Crome browser, pls check and reply which browser is problematic.

Comment: @MarmiK I use Chrome as well. It is something which you will notice when you look very carefully. It happens almost invisible and very fast.  When hovering item 5 and 6, you see the difference in behavioral between those two. On hover of item 5 it keeps his inset bottom shadow while the top, right and left inset shadow are being added. When hovering item 6, the inset bottom shadow dissapears for a short time, before returning. I will set the shadow opacity to 1 and make the transition longer, so the problem will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make transitions with box-shadow, the elements of the box-shadow must make "pairs" and must match the "class" of the shadow. 
Pixels and colors can be transitioned, keywords not.

Your base element is

```
.menu li {
    box-shadow:     0 -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,   
                  2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),      
                  2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);   
}
```

and you can transition correctly to this:

```
   .menu li:hover {
        box-shadow:     -1px -1px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,
                        2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), 
                        2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);   
    }
```

Because the first element is inset and both cases, and the other 2 aren't in both cases.

The last child is

```
li:last-child.menu-item {
    box-shadow: -9px 0px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,  
                 0px -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,   /* PROBLEM HERE     */
                 2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),     
                 2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);     
    }
```

And the second element is inset and doesn't match the second in the hover that is not inset. THIS is the part that fails.

Once understood where the problems is there are several solutions. May be the easier is to set only 1 inset that has both x and y offsets:

```
li:last-child.menu-item {
    box-shadow: -9px -9px 5px -5px rgba(0,0,0, 1) inset,   /* combined shadows */
                 2px -2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2),     
                 2px 2px 3px 0px rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);     
    }
```

The result maybe isn't exactly the previous one, but that is transitionable